# Server/Client communication issue

Tags: java, serialization, client

I have a server/client program that communicates with serialized objects.
When I run the server/client from Eclipse everything works fine.
When I export the server to a .jar and the client to another .jar and try to run them, nothing happens and the client freezes.
I suspect there is a problem with the serialization [eclipse-javaw].
Any suggestions??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1)Check if your hard-coding any value which is specific to ur machine only

2)Check if your jar file contains all the class files which are required for your project.

Answer (score 1):

Run the jar in [debugging mode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1043077/32090) and connect to the process to see what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

if you have properly managed exception handling then you can check your jar by running it from command prompt as

```
cmd> java -jar yourjar.jar
```

if you have exception in your code either it is due to serialization or some other reason you have found exception or your printing on console to the dig up problem